Show / hide Elementor container if in a specific category
I'm using Easy Digital Downloads (EDD) to sell digital products.
I want to add an Elementor Container (or widget) only on single product pages in a specific category.
For example, I want to add a container (with content) to all the product pages with the 'Books' category.
Here is what I got so far:
function display_condition_elementor_container() {
   global $post;

   if ( has_term( 'Books', 'download_category' ) ) {
      **ADD THE ELEMENTOR ELEMENT HERE**
   }

}

The built-in Elementor display condition features don't work with custom post types like EDD.
I am stuck now, as I don't know how to target the Elementor section or who to bind it to.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

What you can do is to use the Dynamic Tags option in the Elementor display conditions.
In Dynamic Tags, you can select a custom_field, and then select the value for custom field.
The question here now is how can you set the custom field to the value of
the book_category. You can do that by adding the following function to your functions.php file:
// Function to save the custom field when the download post type is saved
function save_book_category_field($post_id)
{
   // if the post type is not 'download'
   // Change this post type if needed
   if (get_post_type($post_id) !== 'download') {
      return;
   }

   // Check user permissions
   if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
      return;
   }

   // Get the value of the taxonomy term
   $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'book_category', array('fields' => 'ids'));

   if (!empty($terms)) {
      // Save the first term's ID as the value of the custom field
      // You can adjust this if you want to save the taxonomy Name/slug instead of ID
      $book_category_field_value = $terms[0]; // You can adjust this if you want to save multiple terms
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'book_category_field', $book_category_field_value);
   } else {
      // If there are no terms, you may want to delete the custom field
      delete_post_meta($post_id, 'book_category_field');
   }
}

// Hook the function to the save_post action
add_action('save_post', 'save_book_category_field');

Now when you set the display conditions, you can select Dynamic Tag, select the custom field book_category_field, and then enter the ID of the Book Category where you wan to show the container.

Thanks a lot. I needed to modify it, but you gave me a great start.
